# Texture Coordiante - Object not working with linked file/asset

Tags: texturing, shaders, linked-data, texture-coordinates

i'm having an issue when linking an object from one file to another. The shader it's using has a Texture Coordinate - Object in use. In the source file the Coordinate moves with its Parent, however when linked it stands still and does not move together with its carrier.

Example Video: https://imgur.com/iaF0Pce

Does anyone have an idea how to fix or work around this?

[image: Shader Setup]